# How to return a key value if a number lies in N ranges of L-R?

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I have a python dict like this `{key: range([L, R])}  i.e { key1: [5,9], key2: [1, 4] ...}` I would like to know an efficient way to find the range([L, R]) in which the query(n) lies in and return the key value.

I have tried the bisection algorithm, but I couldn't return the key values in that.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Try using [segment tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-range-minimum-query/) with some modification

Comment: Do your ranges overlap? do they touch? Is a value in one or possibly more than one range? Please show a significant worked example and its correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more convenient to work with an array where you store all the intervals instead:

```
import numpy as np
d = {'a': [5,9], 'c': [1, 4], 'b': [2, 3], 'aa':[-1, 1]}
array = np.array(list(d.values()))
m = 2
```

So that your array is:

```
[[ 5  9]
 [ 1  4]
 [ 2  3]
 [-1  1]]
```

After that you can identify bad intervals, these ones where both endpoints are either below your `m` value or above:

```
intervals_below = (array[:,0] > m)
intervals_above = (array[:,1] < m)
bad_intervals = intervals_below | intervals_above
good_intervals = ~bad_intervals
good_intervals_idx = np.where(good_intervals)[0]
print('intervals_below:', intervals_below)
print('intervals_above:', intervals_above)
print('bad_intervals:', bad_intervals)
print('good_intervals:', good_intervals)
print('good_intervals_idx:', good_intervals_idx)
```

Now you have indexes of good intervals stored in `good_intervals_idx`. You can access all the keys using `np.array(list(d.keys()))[good_intervals_idx]` or the first one only using `list(d.keys())[good_intervals_idx[0]]`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but, It doesn't reduce the time. I have millions of records (queries m) to process. any other faster approach in python or Do I need to look for other programming language?

Comment: It depends on your data types. If you use dictionaries or lists, it will be quite slow to iterate them. For example, `list(d.values())` or `list(d.keys())` is quite slow because iteration is needed. All the actions you use in `numpy` is much faster because its written in C. I think you should replace your `list` and `dict` data type with `np.array`s or `pandas.DataFrame`s and if it's not possible, look for other language. Can you test which part of your script takes the most part of time?